# List sort alphabetically in Kentico Macro

Tags: list, sorting, kentico

Is there a sort option in kentico where you can sort list according to alphabets ?

Like list.split(",").Sort ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can sort macro results.  As an example, if you wanted to sort the list of users in your Kentico site by their username, you could use:

```
GlobalObjects.Users.OrderBy("UserName")
```

If you want to reverse the order, then you can use:

```
GlobalObjects.Users.OrderBy("UserName DESC")
```

If you want to be able to quickly test, you can use the macro console to test your macro output.  The console can be found ins the **System** application under **Macros > Console**.  The horrifyingly fast GIF below shows you where to lookL

[image]

Comment: Mylist.split(",").OrderBy() is returning Null. What should be inside the brackets ? I tried these and all those statements returned Null from Console window in kentico. 

Mylist.Split(",").OrderBy();
Mylist.Split(",").OrderBy("Desc");

Comment: I'm not user what 'Mylist' is, so it's difficult to comment on that variable specifically.  If you run something like `"this,is,my,list".Split(",")` in the console, it should work.  That though will bring back a `string[]`, which I'm not convinces that K# is going to deal with too well. In native C#, you can use `"this,is,my,list".Split(',').OrderBy(s => s)`.  At the point that you try `OrderBy`, it gives you a `null` return value though.

Comment: You may need to create a custom macro method to implement a sort method for that type of collection.

Comment: custom macro method is a way go in this case. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think so.  It will be an easy one to create at least. :)  There is a guid in the Kentico documentation if it helps: https://docs.kentico.com/k11/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/registering-custom-macro-methods